# take fix length of array continously, from arbitrary length of array

Tags: python, arrays, hash, bitwise-operators

good morning guys, im trying to do quark hashing calculation, and im confused with the sponge construction, especially in the absorbing phase, i have an array the has length of multiple of 8, and i want to take the first 8 value from the array and calculate it, and take another 8 then calculate it.

lets say i have this array

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
```

i want to take the [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] XOR it with [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], then take another array [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] XOR it with value from another calculation, and so on.

my question is how can i take the 8 array value?

thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can slice a list with the following syntax:

```
array[start: end]
```

You can use a for loop to iterate through the list in increments of 8, getting all of the chunks. For example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23] 
for counter in range(0,len(array), 8):
    subarray = array[counter:counter+8]
    print(subarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

[In the documentation for itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) there is a recipe named "grouper" that you should be able to copy. This will return an iterable that returns your list in chunks of any size

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```